# Cannot show an image from django backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am sending my photo from django as part of my JWT access_token payload with the intention to retrieve render and even update that image in my React app. Right now I'm focused on getting the image to show  my custom user model. This is what my payload looks like when I decode it:

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": ***,
  "iat": ***,
  "jti": "***",
  "user_id": 1,
  "username": "test",
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "country": "",
  "city": "",
  "bio": "",
  "photo": "\"profile/2022/03/27/testuserpic.png\""
}
```

I have tried to access the image using this code

```
let { user,logOutUser } = useContext(AuthContext)
            <img
              alt="..."
              className="avatar border-gray"
              src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/${user.photo}`}
            />
```

but getting the error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: do you have django debug set to True?

Comment: @DamianBusz Yes I do

Comment: and what is the exact stacktrace on the backend?